# Need help querying LDAP with the internal contents of the DN

Tags: active-directory, ldap

In AD, I have the following User DNs:

```
CN=Some Guy,OU=Users,OU=Ohio,DC=company,DC=net
CN=Some Lady,OU=Users,OU=Jamaica,DC=company,DC=net
```

How can I do a query in LDAP that can retrieve both users, using the DN and wildcards?

I been trying the following string:

```
(&(dn=*Users*))
```

That gives me nothing. I try extensible search:

```
(&(dn:ou:=Users))
```

But that returns:

```
OU=Users,OU=Ohio,DC=company,DC=net
OU=Users,OU=Jamaica,DC=company,DC=net
```

I have several locations I need to search and I want to find what each location has under their Users OU.

Comment: But these 2 users are present in 2 different OUs! Do you want to list all the users in your domain `company.net`, OR do you want to retrieve the users of these OUs only?

Comment: We have 15 locations, not just Ohio and Jamaica. The idea would be to list ALL users under each OU; eg Ohio has 15 users, Jamaica has 31, so 46 users.

Comment: In essence I want all users in company.net that has a OU=Users anywhere in their DN.

Comment: As another example...searching all of company.net, I want to find all users whose DN matches:

     CN=*,OU=Users,*,DC=company,DC=net

Comment: You've made a **major** mistake with your DIT design. All the books say not to have it mirror your organizational structure. Location should be an attribute, not a position in the tree. What happens for example if Some Guy moves to Jamaica? Or starts working both offices?

Comment: Completely true...an attribute would allow me to use an extensible filter...but alas that is not my case, I didn't build the AD, I merely use it.

Answer (score 1):

The extensible search is not the correct one.

Use instead :

```
(&(objectClass=user)(ou:dn:=Users))
```

It should select every entry with `objectClass=user` and which the `dn` contains `ou=Users`